# Get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when tableview get data from URL?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

My tableview is get XML data from URL,First I declare a `NSMutableArray *dataArray;`

and this is how I get the data in my `TableviewSample.m`

```
- (void)getDataFromURL{
   NSString *theURLAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:GetAllData];//<-EXE_BAD_ACCESS HERE
   //#define stringWithFormat:GetAllData @"http://192.168.10.28/req_alldata.php"
   NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:theURLAsString];
   self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
}
```

Then I just get the elements form this array to my tableview ...

But here I have to say one more thing , actually it won't crash before I add another view...

I add a bar button to go to a webView , this webView is use to load a IP Cam stream video

When I back to the tableview , It will appear EXC_BAD_ACCESS

This is odd things I cannot to solve it...because both side code are all looks normal

If I remove this webview ,no matter how I run the program ,it won't crash...

And sometimes I leave the webView I will receive `memory warning :level 2`

But just only one time.

or do I use a wrong way to open an ip cam stream ???

Thanks for all reply : )

OK,here is the code different I use in my webview  class

This is first version I use

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   NSString *directGoToWebCam = [NSString stringWithFormat:GetAllData];
   self.IPCamWebView=[[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,640,960)] autorelease];
   [self.IPCamWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:directGoToWebCam]]];
   [self.view addSubview:self.IPCamWebView];    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the use of #define which does not say anything about the type of the object you are using.
If you want to define a constant string in your code the best would be to use something like this:

```
static NSString *GetAllData = @"192.168.10.28/req_alldata.php";
```

Where you need to use the string you can simply write:

```
NSString *GoToWebCam = [NSString stringWithString:GetAllData];
```

Comment: thanks , but I think I stuck in another problem is using bonjour to search this IP cam , so the IP address should be DHCP ,it is not static...so I think I need a new solution...

Comment: @WebberLai You need not necessarily _change a lot of code_ if you write a method called 'GetAllData' which uses the Bonjour service to find the IP of the webcam and which returns and 'NSString *'.

Answer (score 1):

Where does `GetAllData` come from? It looks like that isn't pointing to anything. More code, the exact error, and a more careful description will go a long way here.

Comment: GetAllData I create a .h file and declare it like this #define GetAllData @"http://192.168.10.28/req_alldata.php" , then I import the .h ,this is how I declare it ...does it help ??

Comment: try hard coding it into the stringWithFormat:,  like this: NSString *directGoToWebCam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.10.28/req_alldata.php"]; Does that work?

Comment: well...I can't tell what's different between these two URL ..does it really matter ?I try your solution , It won't crash if I switch view between tableview and webview ,but my way will crash...